# Delete last entered value

Tags: java

I save the value in a text file (.txt) with java. I do it with a do while loop until I find the symbol `*`. The problem is that when I print the content of the file, the ultimate value correspond to `*`, and I would delete this. How can I do that?

Also, I would like to check if a value exist in the text file, you can use the equals?

This is my code:

```
public void In() throws IOException {
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter place");
        place = t.readLine();
        if(place == "*") {
            break;
        } else {
            fOUT.writeObject(place);
        }
    }while(!place.equals("*"));
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised your code works since part of it compares Strings using the `==` operator. I'm confused as to why you would be doing this since you use the `equals(...)` method correctly later in your code. What's with that?

Comment: Google for "Java string comparison"...

Comment: Use `"*".equals(place)`.

Comment: for this no problem, but how delete the last entered value?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Based on how I understand the question his code actually doesn't work as intended exactly because of that. He writes the `*` to the file as the code doesn't break on the if and the while isn't reevaluated until the do is done.

Comment: @Asthor: yep you're probably right. But it still boggles my mind why he would use the equals method correctly, and elsewhere in the same block of code, not use it but rather use the incorrect `==` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your posted code -

```
if(place == "*") {
  break;
} else {
  fOUT.writeObject(place);
}
```

Could be fixed with an infinite loop and

```
 if (!place.equals("*")) {
   fOUT.writeObject(place);
 } else {
   break;
 }
```

Or use your current loop, and the else can be removed - perhaps like

```
boolean c = true;
do {
    System.out.println("Enter place");
    place = t.readLine();
    c = place.equals("*");
    if (!c) {
        fOUT.writeObject(place);
    }
}while(!c);
```